# How to make div close to body without any margin?

Tags: html, css

I need little help I am new to CSS and HTML.

I want to make my div very close to body that is without any margin. I use this code but it shows around 50px margin from top, left and right margin is ok it sticks with body. Kindly check my code and if you have time help me to make top margin 0px.

My code:

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body style="background-color: #0c2635; margin: 0px; "> 
        <div style="background-color: White; width: 700px; width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; "> <!-- header id --> 
            <h1 style=" margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 30px; width: 30%;"> my firt html code </h1>
        </div> <!-- header id --> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<h1>` has the `margin-top` (`<h1 style=" margin-top: 50px;`). Remove it and that should solve it :)

Comment: You might need to zero out padding too?

Comment: THNX MAN IT WORKED, BUT I WANT H1 TO SHOW AFTER SOME GAPS FROM TOO OF THAT DIV HOW TO DO THAT

Comment: sorry harry i was writing html comments in caps in my code so the cap came here as well when i typed. i am new to this forum can u tell me how to add screen shot here

Comment: Harry when i remove top margin of my h1 tag, the div in which h1 is sticks to body with out any margin but when i add 10px or 50 px top margin to h1 in order to show h1 after 10px from div the div shows that margin from body not h1 .. can u help

Comment: Dear Harry it still show margin from body you may check the page here     http://secondhand.folkscorner.com/test.html

Comment: That is the body's default margin set by the browser. Reset it to 0 by adding `body{margin: 0px;}` and that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 .classname{
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
```